# SQL: Sum values from two joined tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have tables `users`, `deposits` and `withdrawals` and I'm trying to write a query to get user **balance**.

```
desposits

id  | amount  | user_id
1   | 4000    | 1
2   | 3500    | 1
```

```
withdrawals

id  | amount  | user_id
1   | 4000    | 1
```

This is my current query:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id,
COALESCE(SUM(d.amount), 0) AS sum_deposits,
COALESCE(SUM(w.amount), 0) AS sum_withdrawals
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 1
LEFT JOIN deposits AS d ON u.id = d.user_id
LEFT JOIN withdrawals AS w ON u.id = w.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

The result I get is -500, which I think happens because withdrawal counted twice, like so: `SUM(4000, 3500) - SUM(4000, 4000) = -500`

How can I fix my query?

Comment: Does that query really execute? I'd expect syntax error.

Comment: Sorry I'm using an ORM, might have missed something have I?

Comment: what is you expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use sub query

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id,
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(d.amount), 0) 
     FROM deposits AS d WHERE u.id = d.user_id) AS sum_deposits,
  (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(w.amount), 0) 
     FROM withdrawals AS w WHERE u.id = w.user_id) AS sum_withdrawals
FROM users AS u
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: Remove the `GROUP BY` from the sub-queries.

Answer (score 1):

I would `union all` instead of join:

```
select user_id, 
       sum(case when trans_type = 'Deposit' then amount end) as sum_deposit,
       sum(case when trans_type = 'Withdrawal' then amount *-1 end) as sum_Withdrawal,
       sum(amount) as net_amount
from
  (
  select user_id, amount, 'Deposit' as trans_type
  from Deposits
  union all
  select user_id, amount * -1, 'Withdrawal'
  from Withdrawals
  ) t1
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
SELECT A.user_id, A.amount - B.amount Balance
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,SUM(amount) amount
    FROM desposits
    GROUP BY user_id
) A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT user_id,SUM(amount) amount
    FROM withdrawals 
    GROUP BY user_id
)B ON A.User_id = B.user_id
```